# return model attribute to form during validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using a Spring form in my application:

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" commandName="basic-contact-information">
```

In the controller, if I find that the form data is invalid, how do I have the form filled back in with the data the user put into the form when I send the user back to the form? Do I need to set it as an attribute with the name 'basic-contact-information' or do I need to set a value attribute on each of the form elements in the JSP? I'm trying to avoid forcing the user to start over with a blank form.

Comment: Why don't you catch the http header and store the field you want and call it on JSP in the form with value="what the user has written"

Comment: When using spring correctly you don't have to do anything and that is provided out-of-the-box. If you find it isn't working you aren't using it properly. Add your controller to the code.